# onConfigurationChanged not called anymore

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

My apps onConfigurationChanged is not called anymore. I have updated my SDK API to Lollipop and set the SDK Level im AndroidManifest as follow:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
```

I don't know if my changes is the reason why it is not working anymore ( worked now about 2 years without problems).

In my code overwrite "onConfigurationChanged":

```
    @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

Log.v("Debug orientchange", "in onConfigurationChanged"); // <-- is never called !
```

In my AndroidManifest I declared:

```
<activity android:name=".ChronicBrowser"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

When I change the orientation with my device the Activity is restarted. In the past I prevented this with the already mentoined configuration/coding.

Does anyone know what changed or what I am doing wrong/missed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `Honeycomb` onwards you need also `screenSize`:

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Comment: Perfect. That was it. I switched to a newer API and I have a lot of problems like this. Do you have any hint how to test an app with a never API ? Is there any information what should be tested especially when Android has a new API ? I will accept in 4 minutes. Actually it is not possible ...

Comment: the only hint is to check the documentation/bug tracker

Comment: why in the world there is no mentioning of it in the docs. what is the point of them docs? and they were updated just a week ago useless pos https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#RetainingAnObject